# Flink onTimer call is delayed

Tags: apache-flink

We use Flink to process a huge amount of sessions, each session have an unique ID, there are thousands of sessions each second. The KeyedStream is created by `keyBy(SessionID)` WITHOUT `window`. We found that the `onTimer` callback call is always delayed. For example, with `context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(1hour)`, the worst case of the `onTimer` call happened in about 1.6 hours.

What is the root cause of such delays? Is it because there are so many timers and they are checkpointed? Should we window the session to reduce the number of timers?

Comment: Which version are you using? Are your reading from files?

Comment: @ArvidHeise 1.8, reading from Kinesis.

Comment: Do You gather any system metrics there? May it be because the system is too loaded? 
One thing to consider here is that the `onTimer` calls are always synchronized so slight delays might happen if You are processing Your data for a longer period of time.